# Is there a R package for clustering analysis that uses finite metric?

Tags: r

I would imagine that that there must be one because this is a simple metric.  I cannot seem to be able to find it.  Thanks in advance for your direction.

Answer (score 1):

In R, the cognate to "there's an app for that", is "there's a task view for that":

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html